# C# readonly field is never assigned warning - can it be configured as an error

Tags: c#, editorconfig

Given the following sample:

```
public class FooTest
{
    private readonly Foo foo;
        
    public FooTest()
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var plop = foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Which yields the following compilation warning:

```
[CS0649] Field 'FooTest.foo' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

We have an uninitialized field.  For me, this is a developer error so I would like to see this as an `error` - not a `warning`.

So is there any way to make this an error?  Either in the `compilation` or through `analyzers` or `editorconfig`?

Comment: In your project's "Build" properties, check out the "Treat warnings as errors" settings. You can add specific warning numbers to treat as errors, or treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings `<WarningsAsErrors>649</WarningsAsErrors>` in your csproj’s main `<PropertyGroup>`.

Comment: Thanks @Dai - adding the following to csproj makes this warning an error.  `<WarningsAsErrors>169</WarningsAsErrors>`.  Want to put that as the answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class FooTest
{
    private readonly Foo foo;//this field is null so you need initialise it in constructor 
        
    public FooTest()
    {
         foo = new Foo();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var plop = foo?.Bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: The title wasn't clear, but apparently the OP knows this but wants the warning to be an error

Comment: I have updated the question - hopefully makes sense now.  Apologies for writing a rubbish question.